# execute python script to android

Tags: java, android, python

I am trying to create a program to android which will call a python script. In specific i want to connect the android activity with tcp connection with a java server( i create this) and then execute a script code with some args... In java this code executed perfectly

```
String pythonScriptPath = "test.py";
String[] cmd = new String[2];
cmd[0] = "python";
cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = null;
try {
    pr = rt.exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but python command exists on the system but in android there is error... can i install an interpreter? thank you very much

Comment: https://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: An old post, but I stuck at the same problem now. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Kivy](http://kivy.org/#home):

Open source Python library for rapid development of applications that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

**Kivy runs on Linux, Windows, OS X, Android and iOS. You can run the same [python] code on all supported platforms.**

Comment: kivy creates all the application. i want the main activity to be created with java in android sdk and from there to execute the script of python...